# When trying to share image(or any data) into my app, Why my app is shown 2 ea in recent app list?

Tags: android, android-sharing

When trying to share data into my android app, Why my app is shown 2 ea in recent app list? For example, If I follow next steps:

1. launch my app and push home button.
2. launch Gallery app.
3. Push "Share" button on some image.
4. Choose my app in share app list.
5. check recent app list. => two my apps are found.

I'd like to display only single my app in recent app list.
Below codes is my app's share intent receiving activity xml. Please check my below activity properties.

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.android.myapp.activity1"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:parentActivityName="com.android.myapp.activity2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/myappStyle"
        android:label="My app">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```